# Trying to call a firebase function in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I'm trying to use firebase functions in `index.ts`:

```dart
import * as functions from "firebase-functions";

export const helloWorld = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
    functions.logger.info("Hello logs!", { structuredData: true });
    response.send("Hello from Firebase!");
});
```

When trying `firebase deploy` command I keep getting this issue:

```
events.js:377
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^
```

What can be the issue? P.S I successes deploying once(the first time), no luck since.

EDIT

full output:

```
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! functions@ lint: `eslint --ext .js,.ts .`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the functions@ lint script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2021-08-13T19_50_21_744Z-debug.log
events.js:377
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: spawn npm --prefix "%RESOURCE_DIR%" run lint ENOENT
    at notFoundError (C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\firebase-tools\node_modules\cross-env\node_modules\cross-spawn\lib\enoent.js:6:26)
    at verifyENOENT (C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\firebase-tools\node_modules\cross-env\node_modules\cross-spawn\lib\enoent.js:40:16)
    at ChildProcess.cp.emit (C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\firebase-tools\node_modules\cross-env\node_modules\cross-spawn\lib\enoent.js:27:25)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:277:12)
Emitted 'error' event on ChildProcess instance at:
    at ChildProcess.cp.emit (C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\firebase-tools\node_modules\cross-env\node_modules\cross-spawn\lib\enoent.js:30:37)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:277:12) {
  code: 'ENOENT',
  errno: 'ENOENT',
  syscall: 'spawn npm --prefix "%RESOURCE_DIR%" run lint',
  path: 'npm --prefix "%RESOURCE_DIR%" run lint',
  spawnargs: []
}

Error: functions predeploy error: Command terminated with non-zero exit code1
```

Comment: Hi there, this does not seem related to Flutter, so please remove the [Flutter] tag.

Comment: Hi, can you please provide us complete error, which might help us understand complete issue. This seems to me like an issue with handling your promise.

Comment: Can you try running `firebase deploy --only functions --debug` and share the complete output ?

Comment: @ZeenathSN please view edit

Comment: @Dharmaraj please view edit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was simple -
Just go to `package.json` file inside the `functions` folder and change to this:

```
"lint": "eslint --ext .js,.ts",
```